# Evaluating $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2n+5}{n^3+4n^2+3n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I've been trying to evaluate this series. All I can do is to prove it converges. The series is
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2n+5}{n^3+4n^2+3n}.$$

By partial fractions I get
$$\sum_{2}^{\infty}(\frac{5}{3n}-\frac{3}{2(n+1)}-\frac{1}{6(n+3)}).$$

But I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions on the summand?

Comment: The denominator is $n(n+1)(n+3)$. Let's multiply and divide by $n+2$ to make it $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$. The numerator becomes $2n^2+3n+1=2n(n+1)+n+1$. So, you can split the sum as the sum $\frac{2}{(n+2)(n+3)}$, the sum of $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$ and the sum of $\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$. In each of those sums you can write the general term as a difference of a fraction with a constant divided by the denominator excluding the first or the last factor.

Comment: For example $\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{1/3}{n(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{1/3}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$. So, they will telescope.

Comment: How did you get the numerator equals $2n^{2}+3n+1$?

Comment: @MarceloEncisoJure I multiplied $(2n+1)(n+2)$. I probably multiplied wrong. It should be $2n^2+5n+2$. The rest is the same idea. You write it as $2n(n+1)+3n+2$ and split the sum in three as above.

Comment: The general idea in this technique is to get the denominator to be a product of a feew consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression. Then decompose the numerator as a combination of successive products of those those factors. In this case, a combination of $n(n+1)$, $n$ and $1$. Finally, each sum can be decompose into differences with a constant as numerator and the denominators removing either the first or the last factor. The sums thus decomposed will always telescope. It is a mechanic transformation. You don't need to think.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please don't edit your posts to ask a different question than was originally asked, particularly when there are already multiple answers. You should instead ask a _new_ question where we can help you while keeping this as a record for future users of the site ^_^

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2n+5}{n(n+1)(n+3)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2n^2+9n+10}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2(n+2)(n+3) - n  -2}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2(n+2)(n+3)}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n(n+1)} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
From this point it should be easy to continue. Compute these three sums!
Hint for the second sum: $$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{(n+3) - (n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} - \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} \right)$$

Comment: How can I solve this telescopic series for 3 terms?

Comment: @MarceloEncisoJure Each term can be split as a difference $\frac{A}{()()()()}-\frac{A}{()()()()}$, where $A$ is a constant and the denominators are the same denominators that you had but removing the last factor in the first fraction and first factor in the second fraction.

Comment: How can I solve for the third sum? I really like your solution for the second sum. @plop

Comment: What technique you used for solving for the second sum?

Comment: @MarceloEncisoJure The same idea. $\frac{2}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{A}{n(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{A}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$, for some constant $A$. When you sum you get $A(n+3)-An=3A$. Since we should get $2$ as the numerator, then we should have $A=2/3$.

Answer (score 3):

This sum is equal to
$$
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{2}^{\infty}(\frac{5}{3n}-\frac{3}{2(n+1)}-\frac{1}{6(n+3)}) \\
&= \frac{5}{3} \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \right) -\frac{3}{2} \left(\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}\right)+ \sum_{n= 5}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{5}{3}\frac{1}{n} -\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{n} \right) \\
 &= \frac{5}{3} \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \right) -\frac{3}{2} \left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \right)
\end{align}
$$
Between the first and second equalities, there is an intermediate step, by abusing the notation, the idea is to break the sum like this
$$S = \sum_{2}^{\infty}\frac{5}{3n}-\sum_{3}^{\infty}\frac{3}{2n}-\sum_{5}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6n} \quad \text{(just for giving an idea)}$$
Attention: just to give you an idea, mathematically, it's not rigorous because the 3 sum do not converges.

I let you find the final value of $S$.

Comment: How did you get to that answer? Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @MarceloEncisoJure You sum the term with denominator begins from $5$. And in the first equality, the sum from $5$ to $+\infty$ is equal to 0 because $\frac{5}{3}-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{6} = 0$

Comment: +1, this is clever

Comment: @Bungo Indeed, you are right. By abusing notation, I write like this in order to make the idea of the method more clearly.

Comment: Can you explain how you solve this $\sum_{2}^{\infty}\frac{5}{3n}$, what summation technique do you use for solvinf this summation? And why you break like that the sum? what property do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

In addition to the excellent answers posted, sums of rational functions can all be solved by a computer algebra system like [sage](https://sagemath.org).
So if you don't feel like thinking (as I often don't), you can do the following:

```
sage: f(n) = (2*n + 5) / (n^3 + 4*n^2 + 3*n)
sage: sum(f, n, 2, oo)
67/72
```

which agrees with the answers already posted.

---

I hope this helps ^_^